# If $\mathbb{K}$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $15$, which of these elements cannot belong to $\mathbb{K}$?

Tags: extension-field

If $\mathbb{K}$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $15$, which of these elements cannot belong to $\mathbb{K}$ ?

I know that it has to do with minimal polynomial but I am unsure of how to determine them.

Comment: Hint:  Which is the only choice whose degree is even (I.e., not dividing $15$)?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner all the options have a degree that divides $15$ unless $-12i$ doesn't count

Comment: @Rox Maybe if you think of $i$ as $\sqrt{-1}$ it will become more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal polynomials are (A) $x^2+144$, (B) $x^{15}-3$, (C) $x^3-7$, and (D) $x^5-10$,

of degrees $2$, $15$, $3$, and $5$, respectively.

If $\alpha\in \Bbb K$, then $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb K$ and therefore its degree is a factor of $[\mathbb K:\mathbb Q]$.

Only one of these degrees is not a factor of $15$, and that is the element that cannot belong to $\mathbb K$.

Comment: did you mean to say  that D is of degree $5$?

Comment: Yes, of course; I have edited accordingly